# How to check if focus related event is started by a mousedown

Tags: javascript, dom

How to check if `focusin` or `focusout` or `focus` was started by a mouse rather than programmatically or with keyboard.

```js
thing.addEventListener("focusout", (e) => {
    if (sourceIsMouse(e)) {
        // do
    }
})
```

Comment: Not sure if there is any other way, than to react on mousedown events as well, record the timestamp, and then check the difference between that and the focusout event timestamp for being lower than a certain threshold ... What is the actual purpose of this?

Comment: I am trying to open up a menuitem automatically when it is focused, and close it when focusout but since it reacts to clicks too sometimes they cancel out. I would like to accomplish this without arbitrary thresholds.

Comment: Sounds more like you should rather try and fix whatever _"but since it reacts to clicks too sometimes they cancel out"_ actually means.